# CSS cannot be loaded in CKAN

Tags: css, linux, tomcat, virtual-machine, ckan

I finish installing CKAN in a virtual machine, but there is a problem in CKAN interface when accessing the IP of CKAN website.  The CSS style cannot be loaded in CKAN website, so only html part can be displayed.

When using chrome to look at the page source, warning can be seen from console: "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with XXX MIME type text/plain: XXX(CSS link)."

From linux terminal, whenever clicking links in CKAN website, python error messages come out: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Also my CKAN link is set as http://localhost:8773, not sure if port 8773 is a problem. (Port 5000 is used for login in virtual machine)

Other installation information: CentOS 7, CKAN 2.4.1, Tomcat 7.0.69, Solr 1.4.0 PostgreSQL 9.2.18

Thanks a lot!

[My CKAN Interface Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjgP4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a file similar to `/etc/ckan/default/development.ini` while installing ckan, right?
Try setting `ckan.site_url = http://localhost:5000/` there.

You could also cross-check different CKAN setup tutorials for stuff that is missing in your setup:
https://yorkhuang-au.github.io/2016/01/08/Install-CKAN-On-Centos7/
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.x-on-CentOS-7

Also what I usually do in these cases is search for a vagrant box with a finished setup and use that: https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=downloads&provider=&q=ckan